# orbits/canonical labelling of colored graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Consider the following setting.

- We are given a simple undirected graph $G$ and a coloring $c:V(G) \mapsto \{0,1\}.$
- We can compute the canonical labelling and $\rm{Aut}(G)$  efficiently.

What I would like to compute is the canonical labelling/orbits of  the automorphism group of $G$ that respects the coloring $c.$ That is a permutation $f:V(G) \mapsto V(G)$ is an automorphism if $$v \sim u \iff f(v) \sim f(u) \quad \mbox{and} \quad c(u) = c(v).$$

I think that one way to do so is to let $k = \Delta(G)+1$ and join to each vertex $v \in V(G)$ to the central vertex of a star of order $k+c(v).$

What I am wondering is

> Is there a more efficient way to obtain the orbits/canonical labeling for this problem?

Comment: How are you computing the labelings and automorphisms? If you're using Nauty, you'll be happy to know that it can already accept a given coloring as part of its input, and compute labellings and automorphisms with respect to that coloring.

Comment: Hi! I am using Sage which AFAIK does not support this feature.

Comment: the documentation at http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html?highlight=canonical%20labeling#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.canonical_label suggests that you should be able to set an initial partition, that is, an initial vertex coloring. it's not super clear about the syntax for that, however, so you may need to experiment a bit.

Comment: @jernej: nauty can be installed as an optional package in sage